# Change any field of any object at a given date: how to do that?

Tags: field-update

One of our customers has posed the requirement that it should be possible for field updates to be performed in the future. E.g. the address of an Account must be changed not now, but at a certain date in the future. Or: the mobile number of a Contact. The requirement is generic: the ability to schedule the update of any field of any object at any given date.

Does anybody know some package (maybe from the AppExchange) that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

time based workflows is the keyword you are looking for. Here is the starting point:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245

Comment: No it isn't, because it would require creating a different workflow for any change. Today I want to schedule that for Account A, its adres must change to such-and-such on today + 3 months. And tomorrow I want to schedule that for Contact B, its mobile number must change to such-and-such on tomorrow + 7 days. So the changes will be unpredictable, for any field, for any object, for any future date.

Time based workflow is not an easy enough solution for that. And the workflows will continue to exist, even after the update (or you must remove them after it has run).

Comment: I see, well it certainly complicates things to an uncomfortable point. Hope someone would be able to help!